# How to remove the default the default value in the text box in mat datepicker?

Tags: angular

I'm using mat datepicker in my angular 9 app as follow:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control date_input" name="my_on" 
        [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker" #myDate="ngModel"
        dateValidator placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" [(ngModel)]="my" id="my_on" autocomplete="off" required>                                        
    <mat-datepicker-toggle [for]="myDatepicker" class="date_toggle"></mat-datepicker-toggle>                                                                                
    <mat-datepicker #myDatepicker [startAt]="startDate"></mat-datepicker>
```

The problem I'm getting is that the default value is set 1/1/1970, I need this field to be empty
cause I need validate null value. Any idea how to empty the text field?

Comment: Are you setting any value to the date, as if any improper value comes, it would default to this date

Comment: this.my = myobj. date; I cnahge it to null srtill not working this.my = null;

Comment: When you are creating your model, make sure your "my" property is not setting it to a new date. Just declare the property as Date or undefined

Comment: I've made undefined if there is no value, it works

Comment: @user2304483 Told you, can you please upvote the comment so that it's useful to others ;)

Answer (score 0):

The default value is set 1/1/1970 because the date pattern you inserted is not compatible with the date-picker.